# passing command line properties on OpenFire startup

Tags: openfire

I need to pass some command line properties that could be read by a plugin.  I looked around and did not see anything.

I would rather do it this way that in the admin console.  It would be a single property.

Or, ....  If I can pass a configuration file that I might customize that could be available to a plugin.

So is there a way?

Comment: Can't you use a database as support?

Comment: It is in order to pass a vault cubbyhole token that will be used by an open fire plugin to integrate with Vault (https://www.vaultproject.io). I can't store this token in a db because of security.

Comment: I promise a better reply, however you can store the key on db and let plugin delete it. Hovewer it's possibile to deploy any custom class in an of's directory, maybe src or classes, so just deploy this file to use as classloader with a given property file abs path than deploy your custom plugin using this class.